# Flask insert into database without duplicating

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am using the Flaskr example and would like to show the content of the database with no duplicates, 
I have modified the show_entries.html to look like:

```
 {% extends "layout.html" %}
 {% block body %}
   {% if session.logged_in %}
     <form action="{{ url_for('add-entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
       <dl>
        <dt>Available:
        <dd><input type=text size=25 name=attribute1>
        <dt>Used:
        <dd><input type=text size=25 name=attribute2>
        <dd><input type=submit value=Update>
       </dl>
     </form>
   {% endif %}
     <table border="1" style="width:300px">
       <ul class=myDB>
       <tr>
         <th>Available</th>
         <td>{% for entry in myDB %} {{ entry.attribute1 }} {% endfor %}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>Used</th>
         <td>{% for entry in myDB %} {{ entry.attribute2 }} {% endfor %}</td>                  
       </tr>
       </ul>            
     </table>
 {% endblock %}
```

And the myDB.py looks like:

```
.
.
.
@app.route('/')
def showEntries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select distinct attribute1, attribute2 from myDB order by id desc')
    myDB = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', myDB=myDB)

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add-entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert or replace into myDB (attribute1, attribute2) values (?, ?)',
             [request.form['attribute1'], request.form['attribute2']])                   
    db.commit()
    flash('Database Updated')
    return redirect(url_for('showEntries'))
.
.
.
```

My question is that whenever I update the database and refresh the web server I still see the duplicates:
So is there any way to show the updated values of attribute1, attribute2 without duplicates: i.e. other than using for loop here and calling all entries of myDB:

```
<td>{% for entry in myDB %} {{ entry.attribute1 }} {% endfor %}</td>

<td>{% for entry in myDB %} {{ entry.attribute2 }} {% endfor %}</td>
```

because won't work

```
<td> {{ myDB.attribute1 }} </td>

<td> {{ myDB.attribute2 }} </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is what you are asking for, but here is my answer anyway.

When you create your database you can choose if you want to allow duplicate variables/inserts.

For example:

```
"create table registratedClients (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, clientLogin TEXT unique)"
```

That code will only allow inserts of unique clientLogin. 
If i use this code:

```
"insert into registratedClients values (null," + "\'" + "Kalle" + "\')"
"insert into registratedClients values (null," + "\'" + "Duck" + "\')"
"insert into registratedClients values (null," + "\'" + "Kalle" + "\')"
```

My db will only contain:

id = 1 clientLogin = Kalle

id = 2 clientLogin = Duck

Edit:
For unique in multiple columns do this when creating the table:

```
 "create table registratedClients (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, clientLogin TEXT, chatName TEXT, UNIQUE(clientLogin, chatName) ON CONFLICT REPLACE)"
```

The last thing is replaceable with whatever you want to happen.